# How does one live stream in Black Ops 2 on an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2, streaming

I could not seem to find this feature that was advertised. Is there a special game mode that has to be used to enable the live streaming to youtube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only stream league matches.

When you enter the league match menu, you'll have a menu item at the bottom called Live Stream, where you can turn on live streaming.

The first time you do this, you will be shown a code, and you'll have to visit a Google page on your desktop machine, where you can log into Google/Youtube, and associate your Google/Youtube account with the game. The code shown on the console will have to be entered on that webpage.

This account association will only have to be done once.

After this you're given a screen where you can enable the live stream.

Note that when you live stream, you'll be given a URL. You'll have to distribute this URL to your viewers, and when the number of people looking at that URL hits 10, the stream will begin. This is probably done to avoid bogging down the servers with streams (almost) nobody is watching.

There are shortcuts on the same screen where you enable live streaming to publish the URL to your facebook page, so it shouldn't be too hard to get a stream going.

Comment: I did this but no code popped up. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: A proposed edit to this answer said "Don't read this, it is wrong", sadly the person did not comment here *what* is wrong with it, but since I am not going to go back and test this there could be issues with this answer. Perhaps this is no longer possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my code did not appear so this is what i did. back out of league and click on options. at the bottom it says unlink from youtube (assuming it is already synced). unlink it and then click link again. It gave me the code.